# Gibt es in solch einem Satz eine richtige oder falsche Variante der Verbwahl?

Tags: verb-usage

Vorhin las ich in einem Kinderbuch so einen Satz wie:

> Wenn die Schranke oben ist, können Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger **weiterfahren**.

Mich hat dort das Verb "weiterfahren" etwas gestört, denn so aus dem Bauch heraus habe ich "weitergehen" gelesen, da ich wohl intuitiv die letzten Verkehrsteilnehmer als "ausschlaggebend" angesehen habe.

Spontan würde ich die Variante

> Wenn die Schranke oben ist, können Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger **weiter**.

als gute diplomatische Lösung betrachten und im Zweifel anwenden.

Um diesen Zweifel aufzuheben, würde es mich interessieren, ob es hier aus sprachlicher Sicht eine Regel gibt bzw. ob es eine richtige oder falsche Variante gibt (im Beispiel also fahren vs. gehen oder doch eine andere Variante)?

Comment: Das einzige Problem an deinem Satz ist, dass man nach *können* spontan ein weiteres Verb erwartet. Da fehlt irgendwas. Es wird aber in der Umgangssprache durchaus so benutzt, ist also nicht falsch. Im Schriftlichen würde man umformulieren, z.B. *kommen* statt *können* verwenden.

Comment: Es gibt mindestens noch ein weiteres Problem, nämlich das fehlende Komma nach *ist*.

Comment: @RHa das kannst Du gerne korrigieren!

Comment: Consider to edit the question title to better reflect your question. As it stands now a person just reading the headlines may not particularly catch interest.

Comment: Ich befürchte, der erste Satz wäre in jeder beliebigen anderen Sprache auch falsch. Daher befürchte ich auch, dass die Frage off-topic ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt keinen Zwang, alle Verkehrsteilnehmer mit einem Verb abzufertigen.

> Wenn die Schranke oben ist, können Autos und Motorräder weiterfahren
>   und die Fußgänger weitergehen.

wäre eine gänzlich unspektakuläre, einfache und richtige Lösung.

**Können weiter** ist aber auch in Ordnung und durchaus üblich.

Dass man nach *können* spontan ein weiteres Verb erwartet, ist eine unbegründete Behauptung. Die Schranke ist oben; wir können weiter!

*Sich weiterbewegen* ist aber auch schön.

Ein *beziehungsweise*, noch dazu abgekürzt, ist in einem Kinderbuch aber weniger schön, wenn auch nicht falsch. Ein *oder* ist da mehr kindgerecht.

Comment: Aus den bisherigen Antwortmöglichkeiten entnehme ich dass es so gesehen kein falsch oder richtig gibt bzw. keine Regel die festlegt welcher Verb hier die vermeintlich korrekte Wahl wäre, ist das so richtig?

Comment: Welche_s_ Verb. Wenn man ein Verb für 3 Substantive verwenden will muss es auf alle 3 passen. Eine Regel, nach der es genügt, auf das erste, das letzte oder die Mehrzahl zu passen gibt es nicht. Es muss auf alle 3 passen.

Answer (score 6):

Man könnte auch sagen:

> "... können Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger ihren Weg fortsetzen"

Comment: Man könnte auch sagen: "... können Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger weiterzuckeln".

Comment: ... sich weiterbewegen. ... weiterreisen. Gibt hier mehrere Möglichkeiten die unterschiedlichen Fortbewegungsarten zusammenzufassen. Meines Erachtens nach sind die Zweifel berechtigt und ich würde eine allgemein zutreffende Variante wählen.

Answer (score 4):

Das verwendete Verb muss auf alle drei Arten von Verkehrsteilnehmern anwendbar sein. Da »weiterfahren« für Fußgänger ungültig ist und »weitergehen« für Autos und Motorräder, muss ein anderes Verb her.

> Wenn die Schranke oben ist, können sich Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger
>   weiterbewegen.

Eine andere Möglichkeit ist, zwei Verben zu verwenden.

> Wenn die Schranke oben ist, können Autos, Motorräder und Fußgänger
>   weiterfahren bzw. weitergehen (*oder:* weiterfahren bzw. -gehen).

Wie Janka schon richtig kommentiert hat, ist auch deine eigene Lösung realisierbar.

Comment: Eine alte Bedeutung von »fahren« ist »reisen«. »Durch die Lande fahren« konnte man auch zu Fuß. Aber ich gebe zu, dass diese Bedeutung heute kaum noch jemandem bekannt ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast klingt interessant was bedeutet in dem Zusammenhang "alt"?

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Ich schätze mal 200 Jahre und älter. Jedenfalls hörten Fußgänger auf zu *fahren* lange bevor Bahnschranken, Autos und Motorräder erfunden wurden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Fuhrwerke sind wenn ich das richtige Bild im Kopf hab ja auch nicht notwendigerweise sitzend gelenkt wurden. Es würde mich schon interessieren, ob man das irgendwo in der Literatur auffinden würde.

Comment: Ich habe nicht von Fuhrwerken gesprochen, sondern vom Zufußgehen. Dass das Verb *»fahren«* mit *»Fahrt«, »führen«* und *»Fuhre«* verwandt ist, kann jeder leicht nachvollziehen. Es ist aber auch mit der *»Furt«* und der *»Fährte«* sowie mit *»fertig«* verwandt. Auch der *»Gefährte«* stammt von derselben Wurzel ab, und diese Wurzel ist das althochdeutsche Wort *»faran«*. Das Neuhochdeutsche Wort *»fahren«* bedeutete ursprünglich jede Form der Fortbewegung (gehen, schwimmen, reiten) die einen von A nach B brachte. z.B.: *»der Senn fährt zu Berge«*.

Comment: Eine zweite Bedeutung, die heute auch noch erhalten ist, ist *schnelle Bewegung*. z.B.: *»der Fuchs fährt aus dem Bau«* oder *»der Blitz fährt vom Himmel«*. Davon abgeleitet bedeutet *fahren* auch eine Handbewegung, die aber auch langsam sein kann: *»Georg fuhr mit der Hand über Irenes weiches Haar.«*